# Sonar analysis of Razor .cshtml files

Tags: c#, html, razor, sonarqube

Is there any way to analysis Razor `.cshtml` files that are largely made of just html?

I have many pages which are just vanilla html but have the file extension of `.cshtml`. I know Sonar has a HTML plugin but it does not pick up these files.

If not is there any future plans for analysing Razor/`.cshtml` files?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the file suffix for the HTML plugin? http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-FileSuffixes

Comment: is there anything news?